# Combining three lists into a list of 3-tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I am trying to write a function that takes three lists as arguments and creates one list with a triple from each list consecutively.

The example I was given is this: `zip3Lists [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] ['a', 'b', 'c']` would produce `[(1, 4, 'a'),  (2, 5, 'b'), (3, 6, 'c')]`.

What I have so far is this:

```
zipThree [] [] [] = []
zipThree [] [] [x] = [x]
zipThree [] [x] [] = [x]
zipThree [x] [] [] = [x]
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
```

and it is giving me this error:

```
haskell1.hs:32:33: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: c ~ (c, c, c)
      Expected type: [c]
        Actual type: [(c, c, c)]
    • In the expression: (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
      In an equation for ‘zipThree’:
          zipThree (x : xs) (y : ys) (z : zs) = (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
    • Relevant bindings include
        zs :: [c] (bound at haskell1.hs:32:27)
        z :: c (bound at haskell1.hs:32:25)
        ys :: [c] (bound at haskell1.hs:32:20)
        y :: c (bound at haskell1.hs:32:18)
        xs :: [c] (bound at haskell1.hs:32:13)
        x :: c (bound at haskell1.hs:32:11)
        (Some bindings suppressed; use -fmax-relevant-binds=N or -fno-max-relevant-binds)
```

Comment: What do you expect should be the result of `zipThree [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, 'd']`? A list of length 3 or 4? What does your implementation do? Does it make sense?

Comment: we are assuming that every list is the same length and so not handling the case you mention

Comment: @Vic But you have explicit cases for different-length lists, so you *are* handling it. The question is: are you handling it the way you intended to? (Sounds like no, if you were not intending to handle it!)

Comment: I get the impression that this is a homework-related question, which is fine, but for other people coming by this question in the future, this function is built-in and called `zip3`. The general case, when you want to combine *n* lists, can be addressed with the `ZipList` applicative functor.

Answer (score 7):

First of all let's add a type signature. From the question it seems as if the following type signature is appropriate:
`zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]`

This takes 3 lists (containing possibly different types of objects) and then produces a list of triples.

You handle the empty list case fine:
`zipThree [] [] [] = []`

Then the problem occurs. As stated in the comments you have cases for the lists having different lengths but that give a different type of output.

I'll annotate the types next to each line so you can see:

```
zipThree [] [] [x] = [x] :: [c]
zipThree [] [x] [] = [x] :: [b]
zipThree [x] [] [] = [x] :: [a]
```

These don't fit with the other two cases that have type `[(a, b, c)]`.

You mentioned in the comments that you will just presume the lengths are the same size therefore just removing these cases is sufficient. This gives:

```
zipThree [] [] [] = []
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
```

Which provides the correct output (`[(1, 4, 'a'),  (2, 5, 'b'), (3, 6, 'c')]`) for the input you gave (`[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] ['a', 'b', 'c']`).

This function of course will fail on inputs where the lists are of different lengths. One way to stop a straight up error and allow you to handle the issue would be to wrap the result in a Maybe.

First we need to change the type to:
`zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> Maybe [(a, b, c)]`

The Maybe data type can either be a value wrapped in Just so `Just a` or `Nothing`.

For the empty list we want to give just the empty list:
`zipThree [] [] [] = Just []`.

Naturally you might think that the next case should be:
`zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = Just $ (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs`.

But this doesn't work. Don't forget `zipThree xs ys zs` now has type `Maybe [(a, b, c)]` whereas `(x, y, z)` has type `(a, b, c)` so we can't add it to the list.

What we need to do is check the result of `zipThree xs ys zs` if it failed at some point during the recursion then it will be `Nothing` so we just want to pass that `Nothing` along again. If it succeeded and gave us `Just as` then we want to add our `(x, y, z)` to that list. We can check which case is relevant using `case of`:

```
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = case zipThree xs ys zs of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just as -> Just $ (x, y, z) : as
```

We will know our lists aren't the same length if at some point during the recursion some lists are empty and others aren't. This doesn't match either pattern we have at the moment `[] [] []` or `(x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs)` so we need one final catch all case to give us that `Nothing` and prevent the error:

`zipThree _ _ _ = Nothing`

This gives a final definition of:

```
zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> Maybe [(a, b, c)]
zipThree [] [] [] = Just []
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = case zipThree xs ys zs of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just as -> Just $ (x, y, z) : as
zipThree _ _ _ = Nothing
```

The results for the examples are:

`zipThree [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] = Nothing`

and

`zipThree [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] ['a', 'b', 'c'] = Just [(1, 4, 'a'),  (2, 5, 'b'), (3, 6, 'c')]`.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask for clarification :)

EDIT: As suggested in the comments the following definitions would stop short in the case the lists are different lengths:

```
zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
zipThree _ _ _ = []

zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> Maybe [(a, b, c)]
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = case zipThree xs ys zs of
    Nothing -> Just [(x, y, z)] -- Change is here
    Just as -> Just $ (x, y, z) : as
zipThree _ _ _ = Nothing
```

P.S. Thanks to the guy who added the missing Just in an edit.

Comment: I think it would pay to also give an implementation that stops short on uneven lists, like `zipWith3` in the standard library does.

Comment: @dfeuer Good suggestion, I've added the definitions to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is this `ZipList` type defined in `Control.Applicative` module which is in fact exactly thought for this job.

`ZipList` type is derived from the `List` type like

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }
                    deriving ( Show, Eq, Ord, Read, Functor, Foldable
                             , Generic, Generic1)
```

Unlike normal `List`s it's `Applicative` instance does not work on combinations but one to one on corresponding elements like zipping. Hence the name `ZipList`. This is the `Applicative` instance of `ZipList`

```
instance Applicative ZipList where
    pure x = ZipList (repeat x)
    liftA2 f (ZipList xs) (ZipList ys) = ZipList (zipWith f xs ys)
```

The advantage of `zipList` is we chain up indefinitely many lists to zip with. So when `zipWith7` is not sufficient you may still carry on with a `ZipList`. So here is the code;

```
import Control.Applicative

zip'mAll :: [Int] -> [Int] -> String -> [(Int,Int,Char)]
zip'mAll xs ys cs = getZipList $ (,,) <$> ZipList xs <*> ZipList ys <*> ZipList cs

*Main> zip'mAll [1,2,3] [4,5,6] "abc"
[(1,4,'a'),(2,5,'b'),(3,6,'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need a type signature, as stated by James Burton, who lists a suitable one also:

```
zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]
```

Essentially, this type signature says that, given three lists of any type a, b or c, a list of three-value tuples whose type is (a, b, c) shall be produced.

If we disregard the need to handle invalid cases (empty lists, variable-length lists), we next need to implement a valid case which produces the correct tuple from the lists given. Your statement

```
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
```

is valid. Therefore, thus far we have:

```
zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
```

The problem occurs when you introduce the cases for your invalid lists:

```
zipThree [] [] [x] = [x]
zipThree [] [x] [] = [x]
zipThree [x] [] [] = [x]
```

When one of these cases is matched, the type attempting to be bound is invalid due to being of type [x], where type (x, y, z) is expected.

You could exhaustively attempt to match base cases before recursively accessing the function again. However, you could also simply declare the case

```
zipThree _ _ _ = []
```

after, which will end the recursion with invalid input.

Putting this altogether, we are left with:

```
zipThree :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]
zipThree (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x, y, z) : zipThree xs ys zs
zipThree _ _ _                = []
```

What's good about this implementation is that the recursion ends when any list is empty, thus stopping short for uneven lists, e.g.

```
zipThree [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [7, 8]
```

would produce

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8)]
```

Good luck!

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer